# Center horizontal navbar in list on flexible width page

Tags: html, css, list, css-position, navbar

I've seen similar questions to this already, and I've been trying to fit the code to my own situation, but I'm just not finding a solution to this problem.

I need a centered horizontal navbar with has an image with text below it. I have everything in place, I just cannot get the list as a whole to center within the page.

Here is my css:

```
#mainnav { 
width: 100%;
text-align: center; }
#mainnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;}
#mainnav li {
display: inline;
float: left;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-right: 3%;
margin-top: 10px; }
#mainnav a {
display: block;
margin-right: 0% auto;
padding-left: 0% auto; }
```

This is my html:

```
<div id="mainnav">
<ul><li> <a href="about.html"><img src="images/information_sm.png" border="0" /></a>
<a href="about.html">About Us</a> </li>
<li> <a href="progs.html"><img src="images/power_sm.png" border="0" /></a>
<a href="progs.html">Programs and Initiatives</a> </li>
<li> <a href="resources.html"><img src="images/documents_sm.png" border="0" /> </a>
<a href="resources.html">Resources</a> </li>      
<li><a href="feedback.html"><img src="images/mic_sm.png" border="0"></a>
<a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
<li><a href="faqs.html"><img src="images/help_sm.png" border="0"></a>
<a href="faqs.html">FAQs</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html"><img src="images/announcement_sm.png" border="0"></a>
<a href="news.html">News & Events</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

So I have an icon, then directly below it is the text. Those are centered relative to each other, but then the whole thing needs to be centered on the page.

I am close, but it's spread out too much because of that "margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%" specification under the li. If I change that, it slides to the left. How do I get it centered and have it not be so wide, with so much space between each list item?

Also, yes, I do need to have flexible width as it's a requirement by my work that I am building this page for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your css as follows: You cannot horizontally align floated elements

```
#mainnav { 
width: 100%;
text-align: center; }
#mainnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;}
#mainnav li {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-right: 3%;
margin-top: 10px; }
#mainnav a {
display: block;
margin-right: 0% auto;
padding-left: 0% auto; }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/FM2df/1/ for results

Comment: When I looked at other people's fixed for centering a navbar like this, 80% of them used that float fix. But my issue is that I can't use the percentages - that spreads the navbar out waaaaay too much and the typical screen size people will be opening this site in will be on the smaller scale - I have to fit the parameters of what my company wants me to create. And if I make the screen width smaller than about 900px, the last menu item drops down to the next line, rather than having narrower margins on either end. Any ideas with that in mind?

Comment: Also, if I remove the float they run vertically, not horizontally on the page. And I need the links to be next to eachother on a horizontal navbar.

Comment: inline-block; should do it for you? See the fiddle!